# Marginal Probability of joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Consider random variables X,Y,Z with joint distribution

x=1,....y-1,
y=2,3,....z-1;
z=3,4....
and 0< q <1

p+q=1
$$
Pr(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)=p^3  q^{z-3}
$$
What is the marginal probability of random variable X?

I found $$Pr(X=x)=p  q^{x-1}$$ Does it correct ? Because ı can not show the following equality 
$$
\sum_{x}  Pr(X=x)=1
$$
 Can someone show me how to prove the above equality with my answer or your answers ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, that is correct.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=x)~=~&\sum_{y=x+1}^\infty\,\sum_{z=y+1}^{\infty} p^3(1-p)^{z-3}~\mathbf 1_{x\in\{1,2,..\}}\\[1ex]=~& p(1-p)^{x-1}\left(\sum_{y-x=1}^\infty\,p(1-p)^{y-x-1}\left(\sum_{z-y=1}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{z-y-1}\right)\right)~\mathbf 1_{x\in\{1,2,..\}} \\[1ex]=~& p(1-p)^{x-1} \mathbf 1_{x\in\{1,2,..\}} \end{align}$$

You should at this point recognise this as a geometric distribution, that of a count of trials until the first success in an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate $p$.

---

PS: Also recall the geometric series closed form: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty r^{k-1} = \frac{1}{1-r}$$